# How to dialkylate a cyclohexene, and convert a carbonyl to an alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

[image]

I'm trying to design a synthesis of D from C. All I can think of is using $\ce{Me2CuLi}$ to add the methyl group to the alkene. I thought maybe then if isobutyl bromide was in the reaction mixture when $\ce{Me2CuLi}$ pushed the negative charge onto the oxygen and it came back down that could do an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ with isobutyl bromide, but I've never seen that before. Then for converting the carbonyl to an alkene I have no idea.

Comment: The [Wittig reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittig_reaction) may be useful.

Comment: Ah of course, the Wittig reaction with $H_3C-^+PPh_3$ as the phosphonium salt? Just the dialkylation I'm not sure about now.

Comment: I was thinking of Baylis-Hillman to add the isobutyl group, but I don’t think that works well enough with alkyl halides =C

Answer (score 9):

You are right about using the Gilman in a 1,4-[Michael addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_reaction). The enolate created from this can then be used in the nucleophilic attack of a haloalkane. Then all that's left to do is a [Wittig reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittig_reaction), swapping the carbonyl oxygen for a carbon. The full stepwise synthesis would be:

[image]

Comment: Could also use Tebbe/Petasis methylenation

Comment: Alkylation of the enolate with isobutyl bromide will likely give substantial elimination. 3-Bromo-2-methylprop-1-ene will be more reactive and not undergo elimination. Reduce the double bond with Pd/C/H2. Alternatively, trap the enolate with isobutyraldehyde, dehydrate with acid and hydrogenate.